# Implement Audio Trimming in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-recording, resize-crop

I want to implement audio trimming in iOS, I want something like a two way slider that the user can slide over a particular period of the recorded audio, and then I will save that audio.

Are there any libraries available for it?

Comment: Did you search on same before post question at here?

Comment: I did search for the same I only came across this
[https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQAudioRecorderController] 
Doesn't seem helpful as the demo app itself doesn't run